# I am adding attachments to my mail but it is sending empty attachments

Tags: c#

I am adding attachments to my mail but it is sending empty attachments.
I am looking for a quick solution please answer this.

I am adding attachments to my mail but it is sending empty attachments.
I am looking for a quick solution please answer this.

my API code->

```
        var UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        UserId = UserId.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
        {

            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.  
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider>(new MemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());
            //access form data  
            NameValueCollection formData = provider.FormData;
            //access files  
            IList<HttpContent> files = provider.Files;
            List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
            List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();
            List<Stream> inputs = new List<Stream>();
            //HttpContent file1 = files[0];
            foreach (HttpContent file1 in files)
            {
                var thisFileName = file1.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                fileNames.Add(thisFileName);
                string filepath = String.Empty;

                Stream input = await file1.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                inputs.Add(input);
                string directoryName = String.Empty;
                string URL = String.Empty;
                string tempDocUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocsUrl"];

                if (formData["ClientDocs"] != "ClientDocs")
                {
                    var path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
                    directoryName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
                    filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, thisFileName);
                    filePaths.Add(filepath);
                    //Deletion exists file  
                    if (File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filepath);
                    }
                }

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
                {

                    await file1.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

                }
            }
            ContactModel contactModel = new ContactModel();
            contactModel.FileName = fileNames;
            contactModel.FilePath = filePaths;
            contactModel.ToEmail = formData["To"];
            contactModel.Message = formData["Message"];
            contactModel.Subject = formData["Subject"];
            contactModel.ContactId = Convert.ToInt64(formData["ContactId"]);
            contactModel.ContentStream = inputs;
            contactModel.ContactTypeId = 2;//Check Enums->ContactTypeId for more description
            bool status = await _ContactService.ContactByEmail(contactModel);

            HttpResponses.CreateResponsesMessage(HttpStatusCodeEnum.Ok.ToString("D"), Resource.EmailSent, responseMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            responseMessage = HttpResponses.CreateResponsesMessage(HttpStatusCodeEnum.UnAuthorized.ToString("D"), Resource.AuthorizationFail, responseMessage);
        }
        return xxx.CommonClass.HttpResponses.GetHttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseMessage);
    }
```

my mailer code->

```
        bool status;

        if (contentStream != null && fileName != null)
        {
            var i = 0;

            foreach (var contentStrea in contentStream)
            {
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(contentStrea, fileName[i].Trim());
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                i++;
            }

        }
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderMailAddress"]);
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        status = await SMTPCredentials(mailMessage);
        return status;

    }
```

[See email screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X57KX.png)

Comment: Shouldn't it be fileNames[i] instead of fileName[i] in the second part? Have you checked in your code that the files exist or are accessible? If not: File.Exists() is your friend.

Comment: No it is correct, it is the parameter name "fileName" as a list in my mailer method.And yes I checked the file accessibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try seeking the start of the stream before adding the attachment.

```
contentStrea.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(contentStrea, fileName[i].Trim());
```

Comment: not working with multiple attachments, your solution is working only with single attachments

Comment: @NeelMusic: Are you kidding me? Did you try putting this code in your `foreach` loop?

Comment: Yes, but whats wrong in this way to write @MarkBenningfield

Comment: @NeelMusic: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @NeelMusic Do you receive an email with just correct 1 attachment or do you receive multiple empty attachments?

Comment: multiple with empty

Comment: Are the file that are saved in ~/Documents/ empty as well or only the one in the attachments?